# uploading multiple files, renaming with form data

Tags: php, forms, uploader

OK first off, I'm new here, so if I'm not posting this correctly, please let me know. I did search extensively on this site, but did not find exactly my issue.

I have a php form and uploader that should upload multiple files and rename the files (add the name & date to the original file name) according to the response in the name field of the form, and the date of the upload.

Everything works EXCEPT: only one file uploads, not multiple files. While I was writing this, it DID work, but I've messed something up just recently.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong?
Thanks.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<?php

// make a note of the current working directory relative to root.
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// location of the upload handler
$uploadHandler = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.processor.php';

// max file bytes (2mb)
$max_file_size = 2097152;

// echo 
?><!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Upload Your Awesome Images!</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form id="Upload" action="<?php echo $uploadHandler ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <span>Step #2</span>
        <h1>
            Upload Your Images!
        </h1>
        <div style="border:#999 1px solid;padding:5px">
        <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">
        </p>

        <p> Photographer's Name: <input type="text" name="photogname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['contactName'])) echo $_POST['contactName'];?>"> </p>

        <p>
            <label for="file">File to upload:</label>
            <input id="file" type="file" name="file[]" class="tag" multiple/>
        </p>

        <p>
            <label for="submit">Press to...</label>
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload me!">
        </p>
    </div>

      <p>Max file size= 2mb</p>
      <p>Max number of files uploadable = 20</p>
      <p>*Important Note: When submitting photos, please be sure that you are the owner of the images, or that you have explicit permission from the owner to use them. All copyrights will be verified before winners are announced. </p>
    </form>


    </body>

</html>
```

And here is the processing:

```
<?php  
//current local
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
//locations/dirs
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . '../images/PhotoContest/';
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.form.php';
$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.success.php';
$fieldname = 'file';
// upload

// possible upload errors (more?)
$errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                4 => 'no file was attached');

// check the upload form was actually used. no fancy injection stuff
isset($_POST['submit'])
    or error('woah. you can\'t upload images without the form', $uploadForm);

// check for standard uploading errors
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);

// check that the file was an HTTP upload, not a sneaky pete
@is_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

// validation... 
// should run a check to make sure the upload is an image
@getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'])
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

//name this file. If not, name by time (remove time function when name works right)
$now = date('m-d-Y');
$photogname = ($_POST['photogname']);
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$photogname.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))

{
    $now++;
}

// move the file to final dir (& check perm)
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fieldname]['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);

// sucess
header('Location: ' . $uploadSuccess);

// error handler
function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
{
    header("Refresh: $seconds; URL=\"$location\"");
    echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
    '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
    '<html lang="en">'."\n".
    '   <head>'."\n".
    '       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'."\n\n".
    '       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."\n\n".
    '   <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
    '   </head>'."\n\n".
    '   <body>'."\n\n".
    '   <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
    '       <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
    '       <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
    '       <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
    '       The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
    '    </div>'."\n\n".
    '</html>';
    exit;
} // end error handler

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a `multiple` word at the end of your file `input` tag. I don't know what's that and it's defiantly not about HTML 5 or something because your document type is about version 4.

Check this code:

HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file[]" class="tag"/>
<input type="file" name="file[]" class="tag"/>
<input type="file" name="file[]" class="tag"/>
```

PHP:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file)
{
// check for standard uploading errors
($file['error'] == 0)
    or error($errors[$file['error']], $uploadForm);

// check that the file was an HTTP upload, not a sneaky pete
@is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])
    or error('not an HTTP upload', $uploadForm);

// validation... 
// should run a check to make sure the upload is an image
@getimagesize($file['tmp_name'])
    or error('only image uploads are allowed', $uploadForm);

//name this file. If not, name by time (remove time function when name works right)
$now = date('m-d-Y');
$photogname = ($_POST['photogname']);
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$photogname.$now.'-'.$file['name']))

{
    $now++;
}

// move the file to final dir (& check perm)
@move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $uploadFilename)
    or error('receiving directory insuffiecient permission', $uploadForm);
}
```

Comment: "multiple" should not have been there, it was left over from a different form I copied the fields from originally. But that shouldn't cause any problems either, so I wasn't terribly worried about it either.  I don't fully understand how to implement that PHP into my code without complete;y rewriting everything. I'm still learning, sorry. Thanks.

Comment: You have to change the part that is related to the uploaded file. Check my edit.

Comment: Sincerely thank you for all your help so far, but it does not work yet. The PHP works properly (uploads a single file properly, names the file properly), but the inputs cause it to fail (no files uploaded).

Comment: Your welcome. What do you mean `the inputs cause it to fail`? First off, you have a single file input tag in the provided HTML code and you're talking about multiple file uploads. How come you want to upload multiple files with that single tag? And your original PHP code has been implemented for a single file upload too.